# Read a yaml file , operate on it as ruby object and then write it back

Tags: ruby

I have a yaml file like " 
apiVersion: v1
items:
.
.
.
.
    somefield: xyz
   .
   .

Above needs to be changed to :
apiVersion: v1
items:
.
.
.
.
    somefield: xyz
      new added field:
          - abc:
            k: a
            z: b
   .
   .

I want to  read the YAML struct = YAML.load_file(...) , then operate as a ruby object; example I wish to add few nodes/lines to it , then export as YAML again. File.write("path", struct.to_yaml) and use it .

I am not good at writing Ruby code , putting this so that the Gherkin file that we use for automation works .
I someone can help with the rb file , would be great for me ..

Comment: Use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to format your code sample here.

Comment: See the first answer on the question I flagged this as a duplicate of